# Error: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.ogm.persister.OgmEntityPersister

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, hibernate-ogm

I want to write a veriy simple example with HibernateOGM to populate a collection in MongoDB, but if I run my Programm, I get this exception:

*Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.ogm.persister.OgmEntityPersister*

this is my stack trace:

```
*at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:185)
at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:135)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:383)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1750)
at hogm.hibernateogm_mongodb.App.main(App.java:30)*
```

hier is my POJO:

```
public class Contact {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String email;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    /**
     * @param email the email to set
     */
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
```

and here you can find my `hibernate.cfg.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>  
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider">mongodb</property>
    <property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.database">rcfdb</property>
    <property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.host">127.0.0.1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.port">27017</property>
    <mapping resource="hibernate-contact.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and `hbm.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
  "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="Untersuchungsraum.Contact" table="District">
  <id  column="id" type="integer" >
      <generator class="native">
      </generator>
  </id>
  <property name="firstname" type="java.lang.String">
      <column name="Firstname"></column>
  </property>

  <property name="lastname" type="java.lang.String">
      <column  name="lastname"></column>
  </property>

  <property name="email" type="java.lang.String">
      <column name="email"></column>
  </property>
  </class>
  </hibernate-mapping>
```

Do you have may be an Idea to solve this problem? thanks

****UPDATE****

my complete stack trace:

```
Scanning for projects...

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building HibernateOGM_MongoDB 1.0-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------

[resources:resources]
[debug] execute contextualize
Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
Copying 2 resources

[compiler:compile]
File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\Babak\Documents\NetBeansProjects\HibernateOGM_MongoDB\target\classes

[exec:exec]
Aug 14, 2013 4:16:57 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
Aug 14, 2013 4:16:57 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.1.9.Final}
Aug 14, 2013 4:16:57 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Aug 14, 2013 4:16:57 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Aug 14, 2013 4:16:57 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
Aug 14, 2013 4:16:57 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
Aug 14, 2013 4:16:57 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
Aug 14, 2013 4:16:57 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: hibernate-contact.hbm.xml
Aug 14, 2013 4:16:57 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
Aug 14, 2013 4:16:57 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
Aug 14, 2013 4:16:57 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.NoopDialect
Aug 14, 2013 4:16:57 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
Aug 14, 2013 4:16:57 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory
Aug 14, 2013 4:16:57 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Aug 14, 2013 4:16:57 PM org.hibernate.ogm.cfg.impl.Version <clinit>
INFO: OGM000001: Hibernate OGM 4.0.0.Beta1
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.ogm.persister.OgmEntityPersister
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1750)
    at hogm.hibernateogm_mongodb.App.main(App.java:30)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.spi.DatastoreProvider]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.impl.DatastoreServicesImpl.configure(DatastoreServicesImpl.java:53)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.persister.OgmEntityPersister.<init>(OgmEntityPersister.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:163)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: OGM000008: DatastoreManager class [mongodb] cannot be found in classpath try with: [MAP, INFINISPAN, EHCACHE, MONGODB]
    at org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.impl.DatastoreProviderInitiator.buildServiceInstance(DatastoreProviderInitiator.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.impl.DatastoreProviderInitiator.buildServiceInstance(DatastoreProviderInitiator.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.service.impl.OptionalServiceInitiator.initiateService(OptionalServiceInitiator.java:37)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:176)
    ... 16 more
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 3.141s
Finished at: Wed Aug 14 16:16:58 PDT 2013
Final Memory: 10M/25M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project HibernateOGM_MongoDB: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Post complete stack trace (including the root cause)

Comment: I have updated my Post, What should I post as root cause? sorry I am newbei :/

Answer (score 0):

Do you have something like this in your pom?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.Beta3</version>
</dependency>
```

Looks like you don't add jar for MongoDB.